# How to make your own delegate method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make my own delegate method for this I declare 'Mydelegate' protocol in forDelegate.h file.

```
@protocol Mydelegate <NSObject>

-(void)show:(NSString *)msg;

@end
```

then in my first viewController I make the property for this.I declare a method clickMe which is call on button press,that button is present in my firstviewcontroller .xib file.

```
@class SecondViewController;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    id <Mydelegate> delegate1;

    SecondViewController *secondController;
}
@property (assign) id <Mydelegate> delegate1;

-(IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender;

@end
```

and then after I adopt this protocol in my second view controller and define the method of this protocol

SecondViewController.h file

```
@class ViewController;
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <Mydelegate>
{
    ViewController *viewController; 
}
```

SecondViewController.m file

```
-(void)show:(NSString *)msg
{
    NSLog(@"in delegate mathod");
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    viewController =[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewController.delegate1=self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Program is running but Mydelegate method 'show' is not call.

Comment: First Thing Where You call your show method its in void then you should use some where.

Comment: I will edit your code and post it below just check it out.

Comment: Is definition of "-(void)show:(NSString *)msg" in SecondViewController? and you also used delegate1 in SecondViewController.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a [useful](http://viksiphoneblog.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-create-own-delegates-protocol.html) answer for your question.

Comment: Since blogs and links can change or disappear over time, when answering a question like this you should include the relevant information from the link so that the answer will always be here.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation of ViewController, you should call the delegate's method..

```
-(IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate1 show:@"Your String Param"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one button on second view controller xib and connect method to that button then after click that button check your console.

```
 @class ViewController;
 @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <Mydelegate>
 {
   ViewController *viewController;


 }
 -(IBAction)showmsg;

   SecondViewController.m file

   -(void)show:(NSString *)msg
   {

    NSLog(@"in delegate mathod");

    }
   -(IBAction)showmsg
   {
    [self show:];
   }
   -(void)viewDidLoad
   {
    viewController =[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    viewController.delegate1=self;


    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@protocol CPUPerformanceDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)getUsedCpuOperations:(float)percent;
-(void)getKernelCpuOperations:(float)percent;
-(void)getIdleCpuOperations:(float)percent;
-(void)getUserCpuOperations:(float)percent;
-(void)getNiceCpuOperations:(float)percent;

@end

@interface CPUPerformance : NSObject{

    processor_info_array_t          cpuInfo, prevCpuInfo;
    mach_msg_type_number_t          numCpuInfo, numPrevCpuInfo;
    unsigned                        numCPUs;

    NSLock                          *CPUUsageLock;



}
@property(nonatomic,assign)id<CPUPerformanceDelegate>delegate;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSTimer                         *updateTimer;
@end
```

Then

```
#import "CPUPerformance.h"



@implementation CPUPerformance
@synthesize delegate,updateTimer;
- (void)updateInfo
{
idlepercent = ((idle/total)*100);
                userpercent = (user/total)*100;
                syspercent = (sys/total)*100;
                nicepercent = (nice/total)*100;
                inUsepercent = (inUse/total)*100;
[delegate getIdleCpuOperations:idlepercent];
            [delegate getKernelCpuOperations:syspercent];
            [delegate getNiceCpuOperations:nicepercent];
            [delegate getUsedCpuOperations:inUsepercent];
            [delegate getUserCpuOperations:userpercent];
}
```

and finally

```
#import "CPUPerformance.h"
@interface SpecProjectFirstViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,CPUPerformanceDelegate>{

    //Ivars

    NSMutableArray                  *processArray;
    //User Interface Object
    UILabel                         *cpuUsage;
    UILabel                         *cpuIdle;
    UILabel                         *cpuUser;
    UILabel                         *cpuNice;
    UILabel                         *cpuKernel;
    IBOutlet UITableView            *tableViews;
    CPUPerformance                  *cpuObject;

}
```

=================

```
#import "SpecProjectFirstViewController.h"


@implementation SpecProjectFirstViewController

-(void)getIdleCpuOperations:(float)percent{

     [cpuIdle setText:nil];

      [cpuIdle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Idle :%.0f %%",percent]];
     [cpuIdle setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
}

-(void)getKernelCpuOperations:(float)percent{
    [cpuKernel setText:nil];

    [cpuKernel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Kernel :%.0f %%",percent]];
    [cpuKernel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
}


-(void)getNiceCpuOperations:(float)percent{
     [cpuNice setText:nil];

    [cpuNice setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Nice :%.0f %%",percent]];
    [cpuNice setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
}

-(void)getUsedCpuOperations:(float)percent{

    [cpuUsage setText:nil];
    [cpuUsage setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Used :%.0f %%",percent]];
    [cpuUsage setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
}

-(void)getUserCpuOperations:(float)percent{

    [cpuUser setText:nil];

    [cpuUser setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"User :%.0f %%",percent]];
    [cpuUser setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    cpuObject = [[CPUPerformance alloc]init];
    cpuObject.delegate = self;

    [self creatObjectsOnView];


    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```